# Consuming from rabbitmq using Celery

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am using Celery with Rabbitmq broker on Server A. Some tasks require interaction with another server say, Server B and I am using Rabbitmq queues for this interaction.

`Queue 1` - Server A (Producer), Server B (Consumer)

`Queue 2` - Server B (Producer), Server A (Consumer)

My celery is unexpectedly hanging and I have found the reason to be incorrect implementation of Server A consumer code.

`channel.start_consuming()` keeps polling Rabbitmq as expected however putting this in a celery task creates multiple pollers which don't expire. I can add expiry but the time completion for the `data` being sent to Server B cannot be guaranteed. The code pasted below is one method I used to tackle the issue but I am not convinced this is best solution.

I wish to know what I am doing wrong and what is the right way to implement this because I have failed searching for articles on the web. Any tips, insights and even links to articles would be extremely helpful.

Finally, my code -

```
@celery.task
def task_a(data):
    do_some_processing
    # Create only 1 Rabbitmq consumer instance to avoid celery hangups
    task_d.delay()

@celery.task
def task_b(data):
    do_some_processing
    if data is not None:
        task_c.delay()

@celery.task
def task_c():
    data = some_data
    data = json.dumps(data)
    conn_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=RABBITMQ_HOST)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(conn_params)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue=QUEUE_1)
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                        routing_key=QUEUE_1,
                        body=data)
    channel.close()

@celery.task
def task_d():
    def queue_helper(ch, method, properties, body):
        '''
        Callback from queue.
        '''
        data = json.loads(body)
        task_b.delay(data)

    conn_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=RABBITMQ_HOST)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(conn_params)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue=QUEUE_2)
    channel.basic_consume(queue_helper,
                        queue=QUEUE_2,
                        no_ack=True)
    channel.start_consuming()
    channel.close()
```